# How to convert json4s JValue to Jackson JsonNode?

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

If I am working with json4s (using Jackson bindings):

```
scala> import org.json4s._
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
scala> parse(""" { "numbers" : [1, 2, 3, 4] } """)
res0: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue =
      JObject(List((numbers,JArray(List(JInt(1), JInt(2), JInt(3), JInt(4))))))
```

How can I convert a given `org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue` like the above to a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`?

For why I want to do this: I want to validate `JValue`s against JSON Schemas, using the excellent [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) Java library, which takes `JsonNode`s as arguments.

I am looking for some kind of equivalent to the [Play Framework's handling of `JsValue` <> `JsonNode` interop](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2924/files#diff-3898d386254daaa9e2b3c1f6c1db03e1R507).

Comment: Could you give more details why you would want to do that?

Comment: Sure thing @StefanOllinger - motive added

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Json4s 3.2.11-SNAPSHOT there are two methods which can convert between JValue and JsonNode:

- `asJsonNode(jv: JValue): JsonNode` converts a JValue to a JsonNode
- `fromJsonNode(jn: JsonNode): JValue` converts a JsonNode to a JValue

Here is an example how to use it:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val jv = parse(""" { "numbers" : [1, 2, 3, 4] } """)

val jn = asJsonNode(jv)
println(jn)
// {"numbers":[1,2,3,4]}

val jv2 = fromJsonNode(jn)
println(jv2)
// JObject(List((numbers,JArray(List(JInt(1), JInt(2), JInt(3), JInt(4))))))
```

Comment: It's not working for me - val jn = asJsonNode(jv)
<console>:14: error: not found: value asJsonNode. Are you sure this is in 3.2.11-SNAPSHOT? Could you send me the link to the source in GitHub so I can check it out?

Comment: It doesnt seem to be on Sonatype Snapshots yet, but you can check it out from here: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/tree/scala_2.10 and then publish-local via SBT.

Comment: That commit is still only in that branch. Any progress on getting that released?

Comment: You need to wait for a new Json4s release (master builds for Scala 2.9.x and scala_2.10 branch for Scala 2.10).

Comment: How could this be done from within Java code? We can't seem to access the JsonMethods object